# I am trying to make a multiple choice quiz in flutter but i got stuck at assigning strings at buttons and textviews

Tags: dart, flutter

As you can see at `listAnswers[1]` i did try to assign the string 'white' at the text view but it crashes my program, anyone have any idea why, I have Class questions which contains a string question, list with answers and a string with correct answer to evaluate, and a quiz class to build the quiz.

```
Questions currentQuestion;

Quiz quiz = new Quiz([
new Questions("Color of the snow is ", ["yellow", "white","grey"],'white']);
 String questionText;
 int questionNumber;
 String isCorrect;
 List<String> listAnswers;

 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
currentQuestion = quiz.nextQuestion;
questionText = currentQuestion.question;
questionNumber = quiz.questionNumber;
listAnswers = quiz.answers;
isCorrect = quiz.correctAnswer;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: new InkWell(
    child: Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new Text(
              questionText,
              maxLines: questionNumber,
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new Text(
              listAnswers[1],
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: show the code of questions and quiz

Comment: post you crash log

Comment: Pretty sure you are out of bounds.

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Reciever: Null Tried Calling: [] (1)`  This is the error log. Now i will post the code, i do not know what i am missing here.